# Need help in querying mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

I have a a few documents that have the following structure. See attached image.

[document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdoyi.png)

Each document includes an array of 'FileMeta' objects and each FileMeta object includes an array of '`StatusHistory`' objects. I'm trying to get only the FileMetas that contain `StatusCode` equal to 4 and that the `TimeStamp` is greater than a certain datetime.

Tried the following query but it only returns the first FileMeta element of each document.

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({'ExternalParams.RequestingApplication':'aaa.bbb'},
                 { "FileMeta": { $elemMatch: { "StatusHistory":{ $elemMatch:{ "StatusCode": 4, "TimeStamp": { $gt: ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:26.542Z")} } } } }} )
```

What am I doing wrong?

here is the document structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ef84e2ec08abf38b0043ab4"),
"FileMeta" : [ 
    {            
        "StatusHistory" : [ 
            {
                "StatusCode" : 0,
                "StatusDesc" : "New File",
                "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:00:46.286Z")
            }, 
            {
                "StatusCode" : 2,
                "StatusDesc" : "stby",
                "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:20.400Z")
            }, 
            {
                "StatusCode" : 4,
                "StatusDesc" : "success",
                "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:26.937Z")
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        
        "StatusHistory" : [ 
            {
                "StatusCode" : 0,
                "StatusDesc" : "New File",
                "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:00:46.286Z")
            }, 
            {
                "StatusCode" : 2,
                "StatusDesc" : "stby",
                "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:20.617Z")
            }, 
            {
                "StatusCode" : 4,
                "StatusDesc" : "success",
                "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:26.542Z")
            }
        ]
    }
],

}
```

I want to return only the FileMeta objects that include a StatusHistory that match the following conditions: StatusCode = 4 and TimeStamp > SomeDateTime

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, mate, I've been quite busy lately. Hope you already solved your problem. Anyway, I think that I found the solution.

As you can see on [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents), the example shows that by default the `$elemMatch` operator returns the whole array in case of match on any element.

For instance, consider the following collection:

```js
{ _id: 1, results: [ { product: "abc", score: 10 }, { product: "xyz", score: 5 } ] }
{ _id: 2, results: [ { product: "abc", score: 8 }, { product: "xyz", score: 7 } ] }
{ _id: 3, results: [ { product: "abc", score: 7 }, { product: "xyz", score: 8 } ] }
```

If you do the following query, for example:

```js
db.survey.find(
   { results: { $elemMatch: { product: "xyz", score: { $gte: 8 } } } }
)
```

The output will be:

```js
{ "_id" : 3, "results" : [ { "product" : "abc", "score" : 7 }, { "product" : "xyz", "score" : 8 } ] }
```

Not:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "results" : [{ "product" : "xyz", "score" : 8 }]}
```

That said, if you want to return only the document in the array that matches the specified query, you must use the `db.collection.aggregate()` function with the `$unwind` and `$match` operator.

The query below shall give you what you want.

Query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$FileMeta"},
    {"$unwind" : "$FileMeta.StatusHistory"},
    {
        "$match" : {
            "FileMeta.StatusHistory.StatusCode" : 4,
            "FileMeta.StatusHistory.TimeStamp" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:26.937Z")}
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Result:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef84e2ec08abf38b0043ab4"),
        "FileMeta" : {
                "StatusHistory" : {
                        "StatusCode" : 4,
                        "StatusDesc" : "success",
                        "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2020-06-28T11:02:26.937Z")
                }
        }
}
```

One last tip. Consider changing your modeling to something that looks like the unwinded document, and remember that one document should be equivalent to one row in a normal relational database. So avoid storing information that should be on "several rows" on a single document.

Useful links:

- The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) operator.
- The [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)  operator.

Comment: Hi Pedro thanks for the prompt response. I have tried these queries already. The problem is that they return also a 'FileMeta' object which includes a 'StatusHistory' that its TimeStamp equals the date included in the query. i.e. it does not filter by the datetime in terms of the milliseconds: "2020-06-28T11:02:26.542Z". Maybe it has to do with projection. How can I get only 'FileMeta' objects that fulfill the query conditions?

Comment: Hello, mate. I've updated the solution. Please check if it works.